# How to block all search engines except Google?

Tags: windows, parental-controls

I'm using Windows 10 and I have a parental control program called Qustodio installed, but my child is able to bypass the security by accessing a search engine that isn't forced to use Safe Search, like yandex.com or others.

Is there any way - with Windows 10, Qustodio, or any other program - to block all search engines, except Google?

A solution for Windows and Android would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Unfortunately what you are asking amounts to a recommendation question which is off topic.  There is no sime way to do this  although you can likely block known search engines using a hosts file or using custom filters alongside opendns or similar

Comment: @davidgo Oh, I didn't know that this question doesn't belong here. Thanks, I will read about that.

Comment: Be a parent and inform your child if they  bypass it again they lose the use of the computer. Stop the cat and mouse game.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows it's best to use the
[Windows Parental Controls](https://news.microsoft.com/en-in/features/windows-10-parental-controls-feature/).

This will allow you to review the websites frequented by your children
and block sites that you don't like.

For more information see
[How to Use Parental Controls on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/666985/how-to-use-parental-controls-in-windows-10/).

Comment: I already use that, plus Qustodio where I added some pages. But I don't know a 100% of dangerous pages. Safe Search is pretty good, but it only works with Google